# Azure App Services isn't available

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure

I've been trying to use Azure as Mobile App service and in the tutorial it is given to choose this :
[image]
Whilst when i try to follow it shows this :[image]
Can anyone help ? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The Azure Visual Studio tooling, however, should be upgraded to version 2.8.1 or later...

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-whats-changed/

Answer (score 1):

As Thiago suggested, you will have to install the latest Azure SDK to get the option.

If not, then you can select the **Import** option. This will require you to provide the publishsettings file.

You can download the publishsettings file from the Azure Portal. Here is a sample image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YV2OQ.jpg

Once you have imported it, the IDE will pick the deployment endpoints from the file and you will be able to publish the App.

NOTE: Mobile Apps have the same deployment as the Web Apps. The IDE doesn't have the tooling to pick Mobile APPS from the subscription. Until then you will have to use the Import option in the VS deployment wizard.